# Dynamic javascript loading and execution

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to dynamically load a Javascript based on the return value of an API call. I dynamically insert the script tag but it does not get executed. Can someone help understand why? The relevant code snippet is pasted below

```
onError: function(code) {
      if(code == "false") {
        var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
        scriptTag.type="text/javascript";
        scriptTag.src= 'scriptURL';
        headID.appendChild(scriptTag);
      }
}
```

Using firebug/chrome inspector, I can see that the script tag is added to the dom but the script is not executed (at least not that I can determine). It is a 3rd Party script hence I do not have direct control over it and hence cannot modify it either.

Comment: Is it loaded correctly? Take a look on the network panel. If it does, are any syntax or runtime errors thrown into the console?

Comment: Does the script contain code that should do something immediately, or does it define functions that you would need to explicitly call from your own code? If you replace the third-party script with your own simple `test.js` containing just `alert("I'm loaded");` what happens?

Comment: If you can't determine whether it has been loaded or not, you might want to try and create a new JavaScript file having a console log and changing the script URL to point to such.

Comment: There are no errors in the console but the network tab does not show it being loaded either (which is what I'm trying to figure out :) )

Comment: @nnnnnn It should execute immediately and not require explicit function calls

Comment: What exactly do you set as the `src`?

Comment: So I tried with a simple script file which contains a simple alert and that alert is showing up fine

Comment: It's a JS file hosted on another domain (can that be a reason - Cross domain script loading?)

Comment: @AJ. Which browser are you testing with? FF and Chrome? I tested with FF, appending script child like you did on a button click, using a .js file with `alert()' and it worked.

Comment: Cross-domain script should be OK, and your test script with an alert worked so the dynamic add mechanism seems OK. What happens if you just include the third-party script directly (statically) on your page?

Comment: @Shredder Chrome. And as I said, using a simple test script, it works. But the test script was on the same domain as the web page. The actual script is on a different domain which might be the issue

Comment: @nnnnnn the script loads fine and executes as expected (it's for an ad network and displays the ad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comments below the question it seems that the third party script is doing its job on window.onload event. Many programmers use this style.

```
window.onload = function() {
    // Whatever task
};
```

If the onload event of your page has already been fired before you add the script tag dynamically, the 'Whatever task' code would never execute.

Check the source of the third party script. If it uses window.onload, you can try calling window.onload(); after you add the script tag dynamically.